# USACO dualpal error : segmentation violation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

While submitting this program (dual Palindromes) to the USACO website, I received an error message saying
"Run 3: Execution error: Your program (`dualpal') exited with
signal #11 (segmentation violation [maybe caused by accessing
memory out of bounds, array indexing out of bounds, using a bad
pointer (failed open(), failed malloc), or going over the maximum
specified memory limit]). The program ran for 0.011 CPU seconds
before the signal. It used 4184 KB of memory."
Could someone please help me solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance :)

I don't think it is a memory problem because it uses the same amount of memory as the other tests and programs(4184 KB).

QUESTION:
A number that reads the same from right to left as when read from left to right is called a palindrome. 
The number 21 (base 10) is not palindrome in base 10, but the number 21 (base 10) is, in fact, a palindrome in base 2 (10101).
Write a program that reads two numbers (expressed in base 10):
N (1 <= N <= 15)
S (0 < S < 10000)
and then finds and prints (in base 10) the first N numbers strictly greater than S that are palindromic when written in two or more number bases (2 <= base <= 10).
Solutions to this problem do not require manipulating integers larger than the standard 32 bits.

MY CODE:

```
//include all necessary header files
    using namespace std;

    struct DivResults
        {
            int remainder;
            int quotient;
        };

    DivResults remAndQuo(int numerator,int radix,int exponent)
    {
        DivResults retVal;
        double a=numerator,b=radix,c;
        c=pow(b,exponent);
        int rPowi=c;
        retVal.remainder=numerator%rPowi;
        retVal.quotient=numerator/rPowi;
        return retVal;
    }

    char *myOwnItoa(int num,int radix)
    {
        char *returnArr,charQuotient;
        int exp=0,remainder,quotient,j=0;
        int rPowi;

        returnArr=new char[12];
        /*
            find max exponent of radix where it is just less than or equal to 
            num
        */
        for(;pow(radix,exp)<=num;exp++);
        exp--; // subtracting by 1 to cancel the extra increment in for loop
        /*
            iterate from max exponent to 0
            to convert each digit into its radix base.
        */
        for(;exp>=0;exp--)
        {
            DivResults retVal=remAndQuo(num,radix,exp);
            charQuotient=retVal.quotient+'0';
            returnArr[j]=charQuotient;
            num=retVal.remainder;
            j++;
        }
        returnArr[j]='\0';
        return returnArr;
    }

    bool palindrome(char answer[])
    {
        int n,x=0;
        for(x=0;answer[x]!='\0';x++);
        n=x;
        int i=0,j=n-1;
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            int middle1=(n-1)/2;
            int middle2=(n+1)/2;
            while(i<=middle1 && j>=middle2)
            {
                if(answer[i]!=answer[j])
                    return false;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            int middle=n/2;
            while(i<middle && j>middle)
            {
                if(answer[i]!=answer[j])
                    return false;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        ofstream fout("dualpal.out");
        ifstream fin("dualpal.in");
        int n,s,check=0,palCheck=0,num;
        char *CharAnswerNum;
        fin>>n>>s;
        num=s+1;
        for(;check<n;)
        {
            for(int base=2;base<=10;base++)
            {
                CharAnswerNum=myOwnItoa(num,base);
                bool isPal=palindrome(CharAnswerNum);
                if(isPal==true)
                {
                    palCheck++;
                }
            }
            if(palCheck>=2)
            {
                fout<<num<<"\n";
                check++;
            }
            num++;
            palCheck=0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is why debuggers exist.   for(;pow(radix,exp)<=num;exp++);

Comment: @OldProgrammer This code works on my PC but when I submit it to the USACO website, the error arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply increasing the size of the return array in myOwnItoa function solves the problem..

```
char *returnArr;
returnArr=new char[20] //instead of 12
```